# Strange anomaly/bug when inserting a value in array using C++

Tags: c++, arrays, insert

I don't know what I'm doing wrong with my program so it's not outputting what it's meant to output.

I wrote a program to insert a value into specific point in an array, it works pretty fine with this code,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main() {
   int arr[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
   int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
   int i = 0, j = n;

   cout<<"The original array elements are :\n";

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      cout<<"arr["<<i<<"] = "<< arr[i] <<"\n";
   }

   n = n + 1;

   while( j >= k) {
      arr[j+1] = arr[j];
      j = j - 1;
   }

   arr[k] = item;

   cout<<"The array elements after insertion :\n";

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      cout<<"arr["<<i<<"] = "<< arr[i] <<"\n";
   }
}
```

following is the output of this program:

[image]

but if i change the array size i.e 7 then this will happen:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main() {
   int arr[] = {1,3,5,7,8,9,6};
   int item = 10, k = 3, n = 7;
   int i = 0, j = n;

   cout<<"The original array elements are :\n";

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      cout<<"arr["<<i<<"] = "<< arr[i] <<"\n";
   }

   n = n + 1;

   while( j >= k) {
      arr[j+1] = arr[j];
      j = j - 1;
   }

   arr[k] = item;

   cout<<"The array elements after insertion :\n";

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      cout<<"arr["<<i<<"] = "<< arr[i] <<"\n";
   }
}
```

output of above program:

[image]

I'm unable to understand that what and where i'm doing something wrong to have such an anomaly/bug in this program.

Comment: what's the point of downvoting something you don't even bother to read and which is actually a problem and genuine help is required, i know the standards of stackoverflow thus please avoid flaging my question to close unless you have solid reasons to show that this is a casual or bad question.

Comment: The array's size is fixed at compile time. Trying to work beyond the last element of the allocated array results in undefined behavior.

Comment: what anomaly? What output did you expect?

Comment: i was expecting 10 to be placed at 3rd index @tobi303

Comment: @HassanZia you were probably downvoted because it is unclear what you are asking and what was expected. People should not have to comment (nor read comments) to know what you are looking for in your question.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad as any decent answer to this question would require several chapters of a good C++ book. Stop trying to learn C++ by trial and error, it will get you nowhere.

Comment: @Dan yes array size is fixed but it's fixed to have one more value than the initialized array..  and it works when array is indexed to 5 and it moves 3rd indexed value to 4th and so on and insert the new value at 3rd indexed, but same doesn't happen when array sized is fixed to 7 indexes

Comment: @BaummitAugen mate just be more precise, yes i'm not that familiar with C++ but that doesn't make me illustrate, i used to work in JAVA but so i'm pretty clear about my concepts with C++ fundamentals as well.. down vote my question with pleasure but at least guide me to a solution too

Comment: @HassanZia "it works" has little meaning in the land of undefined behaviour

Comment: @HassanZia Java and C++ are completely different, don't assume things work the same just because they look similar.

Comment: thank you all, at least i now know that i won't get help from you people. thank you anyways for telling me the difference which i already know, and for your time too.

Comment: I am puzzled why you have such a negative impression. There are two answers that clearly state what is the problem with your code. If you want to insist that arrays can be resized then we cannot help you ;)

Comment: it's alright, I got your point, i know array is a static data structure which can't be resized in run time, but what are our options then when we are writing an algorithm to insert some values in array and more worse we use C++ to implement it.

Comment: did you actually read my answer? You use a `std::vector`

Comment: yes i'm studying about std::vector atm ..

Comment: next time study first before you start to insult others that just try to help :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156393/discussion-between-hassan-zia-and-tobi303).

Comment: @tobi303 and he didn't even upvote the helpful answers (as of when I wrote this I was the only one who upvoted any answer).

Answer (score 3):

```
int arr[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
```

The size of this array is 5, because its initializer has 5 elements. The **only** arrays that get an extra element are string literals: `"abc"` is an array of 4 `char`, with 0 as the fourth element. This array is not a string literal. When the code writes past the end of the array the behavior of the program is undefined.

You can make the array have six elements by saying that it does:

```
int arr[6] = {1,3,5,7,8};
```

The value of the last element in this array will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping only the important parts you code is more or less this:

```
   int arr[] = {1,3,5,7,8,9,6};
   int n = 7; 
   n = n + 1;
   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
     cout<<"arr["<<i<<"] = "<< arr[i] <<"\n";
   }
```

Arrays have a fixed size. You cannot change it, thus you also cannot "insert" an element into an array. Your `arr` has 7 elements and when you access `arr[7]` (inside the loop) you are accessing out of the bounds of the array. This is undefinded behaviour and your code could output anything.

If you want to insert elements into a dynamically sized array then take look at `std::vector`.